# How to merge two files' data line by line?

Tags: files, text-processing, merge

I have two files, and want to merge data line by line. The input files are file.txt and file2.txt.

**`file1.txt`**

```
howareu
abc
zooo
```

**`file2.txt`**

```
123
@@
099
```

I want to merge the two file, such that output will be:

**`output.txt`**

```
howareu123
howareu@@
howareu0999
abc123
abc@@
abc0999
zooo123
zooo@@
zooo0999
```

Is there way to do that? Is there a way to use the `sed` or `paste` command to obtain the result?

Comment: Are the extra spaces at the beginning of the line actually there in file1 and file2? Do they need to be removed?

Comment: I dont want extra space, just want to merge one file line with all line of other file

Comment: Yes, but your input files already have spaces. Please [edit] your question and make sure the example input files are correct. If they don't have spaces at the beginning of the line, then remove the spaces you have in your question. If they don't have spaces at the end of the line, then remove those as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's usually some elegant way to do a task, but you may spend more time looking for it than just brute force.
Not using sed or paste (just shell builtins):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line1
do
  while read line2
  do
    echo ${line1}${line2}
  done <file2.txt
done <file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

So long as `file2.txt` is not too large, I'd suggest awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR] = $0; next} {for(i=1;i in a;i++) print $0 a[i]}' file2.txt file1.txt
howareu123
howareu@@
howareu099
abc123
abc@@
abc099
zooo123
zooo@@
zooo099
```